# Two different styles of Tensorflow implementation for the same network architecture lead to two different results and behaviors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

- OS Platform: Linux Centos 7.6
- Distribution: Intel Xeon Gold 6152 (22x3.70 GHz);
- GPU Model: NVIDIA Tesla V100 32 GB;
- Number of nodes/CPU/Cores/GPU: 26/52/1144/104;
- TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): official webpage
- TensorFlow version (use command below): 2.1.0
- Python version: 3.6.8

**Description of issue:**

While I was implementing my proposed method, using the second style of implementation (see below), I realized that the performance of the algorithm is indeed strange. To be more precise, the accuracy decreases and loss value increases while the number of epochs increases.

So I narrow down the problem and finally, I decided to modify some codes from TensorFlow official page to check what is happening. As it is explained in TF v2 official webpage there are two styles of implementation which I have adopted as follows.

- I have modified the code provided in "getting started of TF v2" the link below:

  [TensorFlow 2 quickstart for beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/beginner)

as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
learning_rate = 1e-4
batch_size = 100
n_classes = 2
n_units = 80


# Generate synthetic data / load data sets
x_in, y_in = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, n_informative=4, n_redundant=2, n_repeated=2, n_classes=2, n_clusters_per_class=2, weights=[0.5, 0.5], 
flip_y=0.01, class_sep=1.0, hypercube=True, shift=0.0, scale=1.0, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

x_in = x_in.astype('float32')
y_in = y_in.astype('float32').reshape(-1, 1)

one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
y_in = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(y_in)
y_in = y_in.astype('float32')

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_in, y_in, test_size=0.4, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
x_test, x_val, y_test, y_val = train_test_split(x_test, y_test, test_size=0.5, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
print("shapes:", x_train.shape, y_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_test.shape, x_val.shape, y_val.shape)

V = x_train.shape[1]

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_units, activation='relu', input_shape=(V,)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_classes)
    ])

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss_fn, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)

model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
```

the output is as it is expected, as one can see below:

```
600/600 [==============================] - 0s 419us/sample - loss: 0.7114 - accuracy: 0.5350
Epoch 2/5
600/600 [==============================] - 0s 42us/sample - loss: 0.6149 - accuracy: 0.6050
Epoch 3/5
600/600 [==============================] - 0s 39us/sample - loss: 0.5450 - accuracy: 0.6925
Epoch 4/5
600/600 [==============================] - 0s 46us/sample - loss: 0.4895 - accuracy: 0.7425
Epoch 5/5
600/600 [==============================] - 0s 40us/sample - loss: 0.4579 - accuracy: 0.7825

test: 200/200 - 0s - loss: 0.4110 - accuracy: 0.8350
```

To be more precise, the training accuracy increases and the loss value decrease as the number epochs increases (which is expected and it is normal).

HOWEVER, the following chunk of code which is adapted from the link below:

[TensorFlow 2 quickstart for experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/quickstart/advanced)

as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

learning_rate = 1e-4
batch_size = 100
n_classes = 2
n_units = 80

# Generate synthetic data / load data sets
x_in, y_in = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, n_informative=4, n_redundant=2, n_repeated=2, n_classes=2, n_clusters_per_class=2, weights=[0.5, 0.5],flip_y=0.01, class_sep=1.0, hypercube=True, shift=0.0, scale=1.0, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

x_in = x_in.astype('float32')
y_in = y_in.astype('float32').reshape(-1, 1)

one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
y_in = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(y_in)
y_in = y_in.astype('float32')

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_in, y_in, test_size=0.4, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
x_test, x_val, y_test, y_val = train_test_split(x_test, y_test, test_size=0.5, random_state=42, shuffle=True)

print("shapes:", x_train.shape, y_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_test.shape, x_val.shape, y_val.shape)

training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).batch(batch_size)
valid_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_val, y_val)).batch(batch_size)

testing_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test, y_test)).batch(batch_size)

V = x_train.shape[1]


class MyModel(tf.keras.models.Model):
        def __init__(self):
            super(MyModel, self).__init__()
            self.d1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_units, activation='relu', input_shape=(V,))
            self.d2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)
            self.d3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_classes,)

        def call(self, x):
            x = self.d1(x)
            x = self.d2(x)
            return self.d3(x)

# Create an instance of the model
model = MyModel()

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryCrossentropy(name='train_accuracy')

test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='test_loss')
test_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryCrossentropy(name='test_accuracy')


@tf.function
def train_step(images, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # training=True is only needed if there are layers with different
        # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
        predictions = model(images,)  # training=True
        loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

        train_loss(loss)
        train_accuracy(labels, predictions)


@tf.function
def test_step(images, labels):
# training=False is only needed if there are layers with different
# behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
predictions = model(images,)  # training=False
t_loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)

test_loss(t_loss)
test_accuracy(labels, predictions)


EPOCHS = 5

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
# Reset the metrics at the start of the next epoch
    train_loss.reset_states()
    train_accuracy.reset_states()
    test_loss.reset_states()
    test_accuracy.reset_states()

for images, labels in training_dataset:
    train_step(images, labels)
    for test_images, test_labels in testing_dataset:
        test_step(test_images, test_labels)
   
   template = 'Epoch {}, Loss: {}, Accuracy: {}, Test Loss: {}, Test Accuracy: {}'
   print(template.format(epoch + 1,train_loss.result(), train_accuracy.result(),                           test_loss.result(), test_accuracy.result()))
```

Behaves indeed strange. Here is the output of this piece of code:

```
Epoch 1, Loss: 0.7299721837043762, Accuracy: 3.8341376781463623, Test Loss: 0.7290592193603516, Test Accuracy: 3.6925911903381348
Epoch 2, Loss: 0.6725851893424988, Accuracy: 3.1141700744628906, Test Loss: 0.6695905923843384, Test Accuracy: 3.2315549850463867
Epoch 3, Loss: 0.6256862878799438, Accuracy: 2.75959849357605, Test Loss: 0.6216427087783813, Test Accuracy: 2.920461416244507
Epoch 4, Loss: 0.5873140096664429, Accuracy: 2.4249706268310547, Test Loss: 0.5828182101249695, Test Accuracy: 2.575272560119629
Epoch 5, Loss: 0.555053174495697, Accuracy: 2.2128372192382812, Test Loss: 0.5501811504364014, Test Accuracy: 2.264410972595215
```

As one can see, not only the values of accuracy are strange but also instead of increasing, once the number of epochs increase, they decrease?

May you please explain what is happening here?

Comment: The accuracy metrics you are using they are not actual accuracy metrics, you are using BinaryCrossentropy which is not accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is pointed in the comment I made mistake in using the evaluation metrics. I should have used BinaryAccuracy.

Moreover, it is better to edit the call in the advance version as follows:

```
def call(self, x, training=False):
    x = self.d1(x)
    if training:
        x = self.d2(x, training=training)
    return self.d3(x)
```